# Visibility type-converter not being called

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, type-conversion

I have a test WPF Window with the below XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:wpfApplication2="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        xmlns:test="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2.Properties"
        DataContext="{Binding Path=TestClass}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >

    <Window.Resources>
        <wpfApplication2:TestTypeConverter x:Key="TestConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid Visibility="{Binding TestProperty, Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}, ConverterParameter='nottest'}">
            <Label Content="Test Label"></Label>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have a test type-converter class which is below:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    class TestTypeConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var valueToTest = (string) value;
            var parameterToCheck = (string) parameter;

            return valueToTest == parameterToCheck ? System.Windows.Visibility.Visible : System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

TestClass is below:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using WpfApplication2.Annotations;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public class TestClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public TestClass()
        {
            TestProperty = "test";
        }

        private string _testProperty;
        public string TestProperty
        {
            get { return _testProperty; }
            set
            {
                if (_testProperty == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _testProperty = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The visibility property isn't being affected by the type-converter, and the Convert method itself isn't even being called (I have placed a breakpoint which is not being hit).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is in the `DataContext` of the window?

Comment: The DataContext of the Window is now a class called TestClass, which I have added. This has a property called TestProperty which I am trying to bind to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binding seems wrong:

```
 Visibility="{Binding 'test', Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}, ConverterParameter='nottest'}"
```

change it to:

```
 Visibility="{Binding test, Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}, ConverterParameter='nottest'}"
```

If the property test does not exist, no converter will be called

Comment: Does test have to be a property? I can't pass an actual value in as the value?

Comment: `test` will be interpreted as a *property name*. Therefore, I doubt adding or skipping the ticks around it will make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Create a resource for the converter parameter (as shown in the snippet below) and use the resource as converter parameter instead of the literal

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:wpfApplication2="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        xmlns:test="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2.Properties"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        DataContext="{Binding Path=TestClass}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
    <Window.Resources>
        <wpfApplication2:TestTypeConverter x:Key="TestConverter"/>
<sys:String x:Key="converterParam">nottest</sys:String>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid Visibility="{Binding TestProperty, Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource converterParam}">
            <Label Content="Test Label"></Label>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the name of property altogether if you do not have a datacontext and it will work, The following wroked for me.

Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource myTestConverter}}"

// see how Converter keyword is followed by Binding keyword and I did not specify property name after Binding keyword.